# SELECT WHERE CASE statement

Tags: select, case, where-clause

I am working on a project in which the user's access to records is restricted based on the user's User Group. I have created a global variable $usr_sec_group, and I want to add to the WHERE clause in the SELECT statement for several applications a CASE statement that applies a different filter based on the value of $usr_sec_group. I am a relative "newbie" with regards to mySQL, and my attempts at writing such a statement haven't worked. Here is the basic logic:

```
SELECT 
   field1,
   field2,
   etc
FROM
  Organizations
CASE $user_sec_group
  WHEN 1 THEN 'filter_statement_1'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'filter_statement_2'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'filter_statement_3'
  ELSE 'filter_statement_else'
END CASE
ORDER By
   field1
```

The 'filter_statements' could be any valid filter, such as

```
'oName => 'a' AND oName < 'g'
```

I am assuming that the problem is a relatively simple matter of syntax, but so far I haven't been able to write a CASE statement that works.

I will be grateful for some guidance!

Best regards,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Your attempted solution will not work: it's not just a question of syntax, you would have to use dynamic sql. Even if you used dynamic sql, it is *not* a good way to manage access permissions.

A better way is to create specific views at various levels of access and then grant appropriate access to specific users and revoke access for others:

```
GRANT SELECT ON MyDatabase.viewABC 
    TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

See

- [The Grant/Revoke Command](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html#SECTION0006100000)
- [An introduction to MySQL permissions](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3311731/An-introduction-to-MySQL-permissions.htm)
- [How to grant multiple users privileges; MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html)

Comment: Thanks, Mitch, for your response. I had originally thought of creating more views, since the application development toolset that I am using (ScriptCase) has a module for managing user access to views/applications. However, I was hoping to find a more elegant solution, one that wouldn't increase the number of views/applications that need to be maintained.

Comment: Views are generally a good thing (provided you don't have views on views on views etc).